# Execute ruby code from markdown tag

Tags: ruby, markdown, middleman

I am asked to to test the examples I provide in a markdown documentation (website created with Middleman).

I need to test if the examples of the API request I suggest are correct.

So in my example I have:

**_example.md**

````
```ruby
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/oauth/token")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
request.set_form_data(
  "client_id" => "id",
  "client_secret" => "secret",
  "grant_type" => "password",
  "password" => "password",
  "username" => "user@example.com"
)

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https"
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end
response.code
```
````

The idea is to enter in the mardown file and read between ```` ```ruby  ``` ```` tags
in my test file 
**test.rb**

````
def run_http_request

  File.open('../_example.md').each_line do |line|
    next if line.start_with? '```'
    line
  end

end
````

I would like this methode to execute the http request...

Comment: Okay, you've described what you want to do. What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: I need that the method `run_http_request` make the API call
Like this nothing is executed... Nothing is appening here... I am missing something but I don't know what it is ( not yet an expert )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to the following:

````
content = File.read('../_example.md')
matches = content.match(/```ruby(.+)```/m)

code = matches[1] # matches[0] contains the code and the ```ruby``` part
eval(code)
````

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's a lot ! You've saved my day :)

Comment: Just did it :) sorry I though I did